# Sencha Touch Installation Issues

Tags: sencha-touch

I just installed Sencha Touch CMD and downloaded the Sencha Touch code and everything. I created a new folder on Mac called MySenchaApp. I then dragged the "touch-2.3.1" folder inside the MySenchaApp folder. I went inside touch-2.3.1 folder and generated my app. The screenshot shows the content inside the "MySenchaApp" folder.

[image]

But now I am stuck as I don't know what URL to use to see my website. I went inside the "MySenchaApp" folder and issues the following command to start the server:

sencha web start

It says server is running at localhost:1841. I visited that link but it takes me to some SETUP.html page.

Any ideas

Answer (score 1):

you have to follow these steps:

**Download and install this software**:

- JRE Sencha Cmd requires Java Runtime Environment version 1.7 to
  support all functionality, however, most features will work with 1.6 
  (the minimum supported version).

  **Sencha Cmd Ruby differs by OS:**
- Windows: Download Ruby from rubyinstaller.org. Get the .exe file
  version of the software and install it.
- Mac OS: Ruby is    pre-installed. You can test if Ruby is installed
  with the Ruby -v    command.
- Ubuntu: Use sudo apt-get install ruby2.0.0 to download Ruby.
- iOS Packaging: Apple Xcode
- Android Packaging: Android SDK Tools and    Eclipse (optional).

Add the install paths to your PATH environmental variable.

Also read the sencha documentation in setup.html.
If you already had done these things then open command prompt and run command:

- cd bin
- sencha web start
  and then open your browser, type localhost:1841 then press enter.